# How can I rewrite innerHTML everytime function is called javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function he() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = "Heroes have dealt " + x + " damage on villains.";
  var vhp = villains - x;
  document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = "<br/>Villains have " + vhp + "  hp left.";
  vok();
}

function vok() {
  var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = "<br/>Villains have dealt " + y + " damage on Heroes.";
  var hhp = hero - y;
  document.getElementById("res4").innerHTML = "<br/>Heroes have " + hhp + "  hp left.";
  he();
}
```

Here is the above code I made function he() is called when a button is clicked and vok function is called after execution of he() function but it's not going good currently i want to overwrite the innerHTML every time the function is runned how am I supposed to do so?

Comment: what's the problem you are seeing? btw, you are also calling `he()` from `vok` which will go into infinite nesting and fail with stack overflow.

Comment: @gp. It's not overwritting innerHTML it writes first two innerHTML of he function and another two innerHTML of vok function, i want it on the way it writes new innerHTML every time function is called

Comment: As written, your code will fail with a stack overflow before the screen is updated. You have two functions that call each other. The browser will not update the display immediately when you set `.innerHTML` of those elements, it will wait until your code has finished — and it will never finish.

Comment: Any idea how to prevent it, would appreciate your suggestion

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "writing new innerHTML"? Do you mean changing the value of the inner HTML of the container or something else?

Comment: I mean changing the text everyone functions runs

Comment: How to prevent it? Don't call each function in a mutually-recursive loop. It's completely unclear what you're trying to do, but as written your code absolutely will not work.